# Assigning value to readonly variable during declaration

Tags: shell, readonly

Is the following type of `readonly` variable definition valid?:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
readonly a=1
readonly b=1
readonly c=$((a+b))
```

Is this type of declaration in combination with assignment allowed/recommended?

Comment: What issue are you having? Yes, it is valid and allowed to assign a read-only variable in the manner that you show.  What do you mean by "recommended"?  There is as far as I know no other way to assign a value to a read-only variable.  You certainly can't do it _after_ tagging it as read-only...  Is your question about the use of `a` and `b`?  Well, you _are_ allowed to use them.

Comment: No issues with code, it is working fine (in this case `c` has a value of `2`). Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed to use the read-only variables `a` and `b` to initialize the read-only variable `c` like you're showing in your question.

Generally though, you'd want to use

```bsh
readonly c="$(( a + b ))"
```

i.e. quoting the expansion.  If the variable `IFS` has a value that includes the digit `2`, it could otherwise lead to an empty value in `c`.   The value would be empty as the shell would have split the arguments to `readonly` on the `2`, resulting in the command

```bsh
readonly c=
```

being executed.

Example:

```
$ cat script
#! /bin/sh

IFS=2
readonly a=1
readonly b=1
readonly c=$((a+b))
```

```
$ yash -o posixly-correct -x script
+ IFS=2
+ readonly 'a=1'
+ readonly 'b=1'
+ readonly 'c='
```

Note that all shells don't work like this though:

```
$ bash --posix -x script
+ IFS=2
+ readonly a=1
+ a=1
+ readonly b=1
+ b=1
+ readonly c=2
+ c=2
```

Answer (score 1):

I like having *constants* = **read-only variables** in my shell scripts.

That said, I already had quite a lot of trouble with them.

---

#### Alternative solution (to quoting)

I voted for the answer here now as it explains the issue rather well.

But, I deal with this issue differently: first, I assign a value to a *normal* variable, and after that, I mark it as read-only, an example follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# first, we create a variable and assign it a value
my_var=first_assign

# after that, we mark the variable as read-only
readonly my_var

# any further assignment attempt will be met with an error
my_var=any_further_assign
```

---

The error message may differ slightly from shell to shell, examples:

- `dash`:

  > ```
  > readonly_assignment: 10: my_var: is read only
  > ```
- `bash`:

  > ```
  > readonly_assignment: line 10: my_var: readonly variable
  > ```
- `zsh`:

  > ```
  > readonly_assignment:10: read-only variable: my_var
  > ```